# Linq to replace dataTable values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a dataTable that looks as below:

```
 ID Name FKID1 FKID2
 1  ABC  -1    -1
 2  ABD  -1    -1
 3  ABE  -1     2
 4  BCD   1     3
```

How do i use linq to replace datatable values as follows

```
 ID Name FKID1 FKID2
 1  ABC        
 2  ABD  
 3  ABE         2
 4  BCD   1     3
```

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Comment: Are the FKID columns nullable? DB scheme could help understanding the problem.

Comment: What dataTable? ADO.NET, Winforms, ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @Garath, `DataTable` would remain same for all

Comment: @mbx the FKID is a integer column in db. can i achieve it. I bind this table to gridview on aspx. I do not want -1 to appear i want empty instead

Comment: @Eve if FKID is integer and not INT NULL that is not possible, if seeing the -1 is the only problem, a view might help. In general you should have a constraint saying that for a FK there has to exist an entry in another table, otherwise it should be a nullable FK making that an optional relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = from row in DataTableObj.AsEnumerable()
                              select row;
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
   if(Convert.ToInt32(row["FKID1"])==-1)
    row["FKID1"] = DBNull.Value;
   if(Convert.ToInt32(row["FKID2"])==-1)
    row["FKID2"] = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: is there no way to skip a foreach loop using something like datatable.select(x=> new fkid1 = x.fkid1 == -1?"" : x.fkid1)

Comment: @Eve Linq = Language-Integrated **Query**

Comment: @Eve - that will create new object and for that i think you cerate new datatable..i.e. you are not affecting existing datatable...

Comment: which is a better operation performance wise? Modify existing or create new altogether

Comment: @Eve - modify current one..its good idea rather than creating new one